# creating two wireless networks and one ethernet network with ns-3

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, ns-3, point-to-point

I need to create two wireless networks and one ethernet network with ns-3 but all my ideas doesn't seem to work as I can't have collison. I was trying to create something connected like:

(wifi) ----point to point--- (ethernet)--- point to point--- (wifi)

[can't post image, here is a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBGnQ.png)

It didn't work, it seems because I need something called point-to-multipoint communication and I don't know how to do that on ns-3 (I didn't even found about it on ns-3) and I hardly find reference about this matter. Tried to just create three nodes and assign two with wireless node and one with ethernet while trying that.

Also tried to create two pair of nodes with a point-to-point communcation between each but I realized I was changing the problem.

Comment: A drawing of what you mean would help a lot.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean by "ethernet".  are you trying to connect two routers together directly?

Comment: the pdf says exactly "In NS-3 a local network environment must be implemented which must contain: at least an Ethernet network (802.3 standard) and two wireless networks (802.11x standard) "

Answer (score 0):

What you need is add two network interfaces for each node, one for point-to-point and another for Wi-Fi.

[Interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCjdW.png)

See the code sample in the **ns3** source code for an example:

```
src/examples/tutorial/third.cc
```